# How do you get the double sum or integral from $E(X+Y)$ (expected value)?

Tags: probability, expected-value, convolution, integral, transform

I was given a proof for $E(X+Y)$ = $E(X)+E(Y)$ for cases where both variables are either discrete or continuous:

Discrete:

$$
\begin{align*}
E(X+Y)
&=\sum_{x\in\mathcal X}\sum_{y\in\mathcal Y}(x+y)p_{X,Y}(X=x, Y=y)\\
&= \cdots
\end{align*}$$

Continuous:

$$
\begin{align*}
E(X+Y)
&=\int_\mathcal X\int_\mathcal Y(x+y)f_{X, Y}(x, x)dxdy\\
&=\cdots
\end{align*}
$$

I am not sure how they get double sums or double integrals from the definition of $E(X)$ with a single sum or integral. What is the intuition behind it or is there some mathematical logic behind it?

I know that for one discrete random variable $X$ where $x_1, x_2, \cdots$ are the values of $X$ and $p_X(x)$ is the probability mass function of $X$:

$$E(X)=\sum_{x\in\mathcal X}x_ip_X(x_i)$$

and likewise for one continuous random variable, with $f_X(x)$ being the probability density function for $X$:

$$E(X)=\int_{\mathcal X}x_if_X(x_i)\,\text{d}x_i$$

I am not sure how to get the double sums or integrals from the definitions I have given.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician.

Comment: The take away point is that the expectation notation is highly efficient and synthetic. The same symbol $\mathbb{E}$ can mean (ah ha) different things depending on its argument, it is usually clear from context what it means, but is a source of confusion for many students.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assume a joint density $p(x,y)$ for $X$ and $Y$ (I have not said anything about the dependency between $X$ and $Y$ here, they can be correlated). The definition of $E(X+Y)$ is:

$$E(X + Y) = \int_\mathcal Y\int_\mathcal X(x+y)p(x,y)dxdy$$
Further, using the fact that the order of integration can be interchanged and that the integral is a linear operation:

\begin{align}
\int_\mathcal Y\int_\mathcal X(x+y)p(x,y)dxdy &=  \int_\mathcal Y\int_\mathcal X \left(xp(x,y) + yp(x,y)\right) dx dy = \\
\int_\mathcal X x \int_\mathcal Y p(x,y)dydx + \int_\mathcal Y y \int_\mathcal X p(x,y)dxdy &= \int_\mathcal X xp(x) dx + \int_\mathcal Y yp(y)dy 
 \end{align}

since $\int_\mathcal X p(x,y) dx = p(y)$ and $\int_\mathcal Y p(x,y) dy = p(x)$. Now we simply have the expectation of $X$ and $Y$ separately and we know that

$$\int_\mathcal X xp(x) dx = E(X)$$ and
$$\int_\mathcal Y yp(y) dy = E(Y)$$ and therefore
$$E(X+Y) = E(X) + E(Y).$$

**EDIT**

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent we have $p(x,y) = p(x)p(y)$. Therefore the last line of the proof simplifies

$$\int_\mathcal X xp(x)\left(\int_\mathcal Y p(y)dy\right)dx + \int_\mathcal Y y p(y)\left(\int_\mathcal X p(x)dx\right)dy = \int_\mathcal X xp(x) dx + \int_\mathcal Y yp(y)dy, $$ since $\int_\mathcal Y p(y)dy = 1$ (same for $x$).

Comment: How can you assume they are joint random variables?

Comment: That is the most general assumption you can make, since you don't make any assumption about the dependency between $X$ and $Y$. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then the joint density is simply the product.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Would you not have to do a separate case for when they are independent?  Also, how about the double sums?

Comment: Also, my proof has the limits switched, is that wrong?

Comment: If they were indendent you could just replace $p(x,y)$ by $p(x)p(y)$ and do the same calculations, but you would have $\int_x xp(x) \int_y p(y) dy dx$ (same for $p(x)$) instead of the joint density. The exact same case goes for the sum, just replace the double integral with a double sum. What limits? You can switch the order of summation/integration as long as the function you are integrating is not too crazy (see [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)

Comment: Okay, I see thanks! The limits I am talking about are for the double integrals, for my proof the inner integral is the $y$ values when integrating with $dx$ and vice versa, would that be correct?

Comment: Not sure if I follow what you mean by limit, but the $y$ could then be taken outside the integral wrt $x$

Comment: I mean the limits of integration, like $x$ in $\int_x$.

Comment: I am still not sure what happens if $X + Y$ is not a joint distribution?

Comment: See my edit (and accept it again if it makes sense :)).

Comment: I am bit confused with the brackets you put in there... and I just unaccepted because I felt that it didn't take the case if $X$ and $Y$ are not jointly distributed but now I guess it doesn't matter...

Comment: By the way, thank you for the answer!

Comment: The brackets are just to emphasize that you can solve the inner integral first and then solve the outer one.

Comment: I see, thank you!

Comment: @user12055579 If $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables, you can always ask about the probability that $X < a$ and $Y < b$ simultaneously. We can define a function $F(a, b) = P(X < a \text{ and } Y < b)$ to be this probability, and we call it the joint cdf (cumulative distribution function). We don't have to make any assumptions on $X$ and $Y$ to do this. This is what is meant when someone says that $X$ and $Y$ are "jointly distributed": it's not an assumption on the random variables, simply a way of characterizing them with a function that we can construct from them.

Comment: @ericperkerson Understood, thanks. But I kind of see it as the question is asking for the expected value of the construction of $X + Y$ and not the construction of $X + Y$ with it jointly distributed.

Comment: No, I think you still misunderstand. In a single context (probability space), there's no such thing as two random variables that aren't jointly distributed like you seem to be implying. Every set of random variables on a probability space are jointly distributed with a cdf defined as above.

Comment: Yes I realize that there's no such thing as two random variables that aren't jointly distributed because its you who constructs it with a cdf. But the question isn't asking for $X + Y$ constructed as jointly distributed with a defined cdf...

Comment: There is an assumption that @J.C.Wahl is making, which is that the two variables have a joint *pdf*, not just a joint *cdf*, which I would object to slightly. The cdf is ALWAYS defined no matter what, but the pdf is not. Is that what you're objecting to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111531/discussion-between-ericperkerson-and-user12055579).

Answer (score 2):

The question of double versus simple sum is mostly a matter of mathematical simplicity.

First, as pointed by [Stubborn Atom](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/119261/stubbornatom), the question is related with the so-poorly-called "[Law of the Unconscious Statistician](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)": If one first defines a random variable $Z$ as $$Z=X+Y$$ with associated pdf or pmf $p_Z$, the expectation of $Z$ is a single sum$$\mathbb E_Z[Z] = \sum_z zp_Z(z)$$or single integral$$\mathbb E_Z[Z] = \int_\mathcal Z zp_Z(z)\text{d}z.$$ If one wants to avoid deriving the distribution of $Z$, $X+Y$ is a particular function of $(X,Y)$, $$\psi(X,Y)=X+Y$$ and its expectation $\mathbb E_{(X,Y)}[\psi(X,Y)]$ is a sum or integral over the domain of variation of the random variable $(X,Y)$, $\mathcal X\times\mathcal Y$, which can be written as a double sum. Note however that the double summation$$\sum_{x\in\mathcal X}\sum_{y\in\mathcal Y}\cdots$$is a matter of convention as it can also be represented as a single summation$$\sum_{(x,y)\in\mathcal X\times\mathcal Y}\cdots$$
Similarly, in measure theory, generic integral symbols like$$\int_\mathcal G f(x)\text{d}x$$are customarily used for integrals over multidimensional sets $\mathcal G\subset\mathbb R$ when $k>1$.

Comment: What is $\psi$ and what is variation?

Comment: And what do you replace the $\cdots$ with?

Comment: Wait nevermind, I get it. Variation would be $\mathcal X\times\mathcal Y$ and the $\cdots$ would be replaced with the stuff in the question. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!

Comment: $\psi$ is the function defined in the answer: $\psi(x,y)=x+y$ and the _domain of variation_ of $(X,Y)$ is the set of all possible values taken by the random pair, sometimes called the _support_ of the random vector. As for $\cdots$ it can be replaced by $\psi(x,y)p_{(X,Y)}(x,y)$ or $\psi(x,y)p_{(X,Y)}(x,y)\text{d}(x,y)$

Comment: Okay, I see, thanks. I have a question which is why is it that: $\psi(X,Y)=X+Y = \psi(x,y)=x+y$?